# How do you skip chapters on Episode - Choose Your Story?

Tags: episode

I recently had to factory reset my phone, and I forgot to write down the email that I used for *Episode*. I tried multiple times to find the right one, but I can't. I was reading this story called Craving Scar, and now I have to restart it. I really down want to, and I want to know if there is any way you can skip chapters on *Episode* so that I can get back to where I was. And I was pretty far.

So, if anyone on here knows of a way to skip chapters, please tell me. I really want to get back to where I was without restarting. The story is almost done and I don't want to start all the way back at the beginning.

Comment: You've initially tagged your question with [windows-phone]. Is this the device you are playing on? Edit your question body (not the tags) to add the OS of the device you are playing on (Android, iOS, etc).